# Generated XSD is empty in Enterprise Architect 12

Tags: xsd, schema, enterprise-architect, auto-generate

I'm using `Sparx Enterprise Architect v12` to generate `XSD schema` from `XML Schema graphic model`. When I try to generate the `XML schema` the file only contains the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

Does anybody know what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the following:

- Select the package in the project browser (and not the Class diagram or the XSD schema).
- Either you select "Tools"- "XML Schema" - "Generate XML Schema" in the main menu or you right click on the package and select "Code Engineering" - "Generate XML Schema"
- In some cases the filename in "Child Package Options" can be wrong. Double click on the filename and choose the right one.
- Generate!